# Trouble with simple TableView in Swift, error SIGNAL SIGART

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

I have problem with populating a simple tableView:
It throws an exception when viewDidLoad is triggered. What am i doing wrong here?

this is the error:

```
Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UI‌​Kit-3512.60.7/UITabl‌​eView.m:6573 2016-09-08 17:45:52.603 petSyncApp
[967:137236] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier customcell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

here's my code in ProfileViewController (which is datasource to the tableview)

```
import UIKit

class ProfileViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myTableView.reloadData()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customcell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Add pet"
        return cell
    }

}
```

and here are the connections :

[tableview data source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHkmn.png)

[view controller connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJ4P6.png)

Comment: Also connect the table view delegate. And you do not need to reload the table in the viewDidLoad.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @rmaddy error is SIGNAL SIGART, and in the console there is "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Comment: I fixed one error which is that i called "Dequeue" method for "tableView" instead of "myTableView", but i fixed that and it still throws exception!

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customcell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

Comment: @user3634293 There should be more than just that. There should additional information and error message about the exception.

Comment: heres the log:
 Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.60.7/UITableView.m:6573
2016-09-08 17:45:52.603 petSyncApp[967:137236] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier prototype1 - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

its got to do something with that identifier, i changed it from "customcell" to "prototype1" so that you know

Comment: You should update your question with all the info you've put in the comments so it is easier to read.

Comment: alright will do that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not added the Prototype Cell into the Table View, Drag and Drop the table view cell into the table view and connect the Table View Cell class to it with particular identifier.

Drag and Drop a TableView Cell and Assign a class:

[image]

Assign the identifier to it:

[image]

Set the Table Style to Basic

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem! and i never saw that you have to do that on any tutorial. This troubled me way too much. 
Whats the use of that first prototype cell?

Comment: Great!! Next time you should post all info regarding the error, so that it is easier to help. :)

Comment: Prototype Cell defines a View for the Cell, It displays the content of the cell, Like View Controller displays the Visual elements.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks!